# Transfering money from paypal to Indian bank savings account?

Tags: income-tax, india, paypal

I have a small drop-shipping website. My customers pay via PayPal, then my money gets transferred to my bank account in INR.

1. Will this money be taxable.
2. Can and will the (Indian) Income Tax department catch me for this?
3. How do I pay taxes for this, if there are any?

Comment: In the US, "IT" usually stands for "information technology." Is that how you are using this acronym?

Comment: Sorry about that Income tax department

Answer (score 1):

This is taxable in India. You need to declare the income and pay taxes accordingly